# JWT token is undefined but it exists in the http response

Tags: angular, jwt, local-storage

The code below successfully returns a jwt token from my backend. However, when i try to access the token to save it in the localStorage it is always undefined. How can I access my jwt token?

```
loginProcess() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res); // this returns {jwt: "validTokenHere"
          console.log(res.token); // this returns undefined
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.token); // localstorage is 'token' : undefined
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you see a variable "token" in your response? No? Because its name is jwt, not token.

Comment: @maio290 I see now I was getting confused by the auto-complete of my editor. I should have used res.jwt

Answer (score 1):

Your Key is `jwt`

```
localStorage.setItem('token', res.jwt);
```